# Coq - How to proof False when hypotesis is wrong

Tags: coq, proof

I made an environment to try to proof what I want/need

I have a posfijo function that says if a list (`l1`) contains another list (`l2`) at the end.

So if I add an element to the first list and I use the result as the second list, like `l2 = x :: l1`, I want to proof that is not possible.

I did this...

```
Variable G:Set.
Inductive posfijo : list _ -> list _ -> Prop :=
  | posfijoB : forall l: list _, posfijo l l
  | posfijoI : forall (l1 l2: list _) (a : G), posfijo l1 l2 -> posfijo l1 (cons a l2).

Infix "<<"  := (posfijo) (at level 70, right associativity).



Lemma Pref4_a : forall (X:Set)(l: list G)(x:G), ~ (cons x l << l).
Proof.
intros X l x H.
```

So then my goal is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should proceed with `induction l`.

Comment: I already tried, can you help me with some clues. Now with this `x :: nil << nil` I need to prove `False`

Comment: This case you easily kill with `inversion H` -- the real "meat" will be in the next case.

Comment: Im still stuck, can any body Helps me? im with the real meat.